# How to add "git bash here" in a new tab for Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows-terminal, git-for-windows

I can open a new git tab in windows terminal but if I click on the button in the context menu "git bash here" it opens in its own window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(As of Terminal v1.16)*

Besides just changing your default profile to git bash, this currently isn't possible. This is currently tracked in [Add a explorer context menu entry to let the user pick the profile they want to "open here", microsoft/terminal#6111](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/6111)

Answer (score 1):

add "git bash here in WT" in background of windows explorer

```reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Git_WinTerm]
@="Git &Bash Here in WT"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Git_WinTerm\command]
@="wt -w 0 nt -d \"%v.\" -p \"Git Bash\""
```

Comment: Now, this is a solution and it works perfectly. Should be the designated answer.